# Android coding good habit examples?

Tags: android

Ive been searching the internet for a while now but cant find a good page for good habit examples in android programming. For examples im interested in things like how to name classes or xml files (what case letters, where to use _) and also in file things like naming variables and fields or edittexts, prefixes and everything like that.

If someone could help me with a link i would be very grateful!1

Comment: I think you should look for Java naming conventions rather than Android, since that's the language used.

Comment: for xml, i use prefix like b_ , tv_ , iv_ , for the id's of views for Button, TextView, ImageView respectively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Android developers](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) has its answer for this.
If you need anything elaborated I'll update my answer from your comments :-)
For Classes use Java naming convention:

- First letter capitalized, no "_" in the class names but start with capitalized letter for each new word ei:
  MyActivity or MySettingsActivity
- For xml object naming you have some other limitations as in, first letter cannot be capitalized, therefor I suggest your either use the general java naming convention for methods (First letter decapitalized, and then new words capitalized like: buttonQuit or quitButton), if it should be button first or last is up to you, but stick with 1 style. don't name 1 item: nameTextView (or nameTxtVw) and then something else buttonSubmit (Have the indicators in the same orders).
- For xml files, use lower case separated with underscore "_".

Why a lot java files are called Activity in the end. It is to describe in the name that they inherit from from the superclass "Activity". It is a principle that came became big with Android, which uses it a lot, examples if these classes are inherited:
(super class = end of their heirs name)
AsyncTask = Task
Service = Service
Activity = Activity
Handler = Handler

I could go on :)

For xml files, belonging to activities I personally like to call them the name before Activity, so MainActivity's xml layout would be main.xml

Comment: Thank you but this is more of an guidline for coding functions and so on ... my question was about good habbits in names - naming classes, xml files, buttons and so on.

Comment: Updated my question, though I now see you have found your answer

Comment: Thank you, thats the best anwser now :)
One more question - whats up with the word "activity" in the name? Should all java files end with activity and all xml files begin with it? If i make a hello world project then thats the way eclipse does it for me anyway ...

Comment: usually, if the java file extends Activity, name it something like 'MyActivity'.. It is just a name..

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some coding guidelines, have a look at [Code Style Guidelines for Contributors](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

If you want to enforce this rules without remembering all of them, and you are using eclipse then you can use formatting rules provided by Android team:  [android-formatting.xml](https://raw.github.com/android/platform_development/master/ide/eclipse/android-formatting.xml). Just import it into eclipse using Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter, click Import.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn Java code conventions, and so read this: 
[java style](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html)

It's good to practice always name classes [upper camel style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (e.g CustomerService)
Class names should be noun,

For naming variables you should use lower Camel Style (e.g myVariable)

Xml file shoudl be lower case and words should be separated by under score

please read the above links!

[Edited] this part added after the first comment!

I don't know any good reference for good naming convention and things like this but those are things that you can find out be practicing! for example:
"activity" prefix may be not useful in case if all your layouts are for activities. but if there is bunch of other style (e.g  dialog layouts) it could help to put "activity" prefix.

another example: I prefer to put "Activity" prefix for all classes that extends Activity, because eclipse shows classes base on name, and this could help to somehow a better management (but it's against Java naming convention! because you should suffix your class name with super class name)

For naming Id: You could prefix the resource with the name of what it is (e.g titleStatus), it doesn't really matters! but you for better managing your Ids and not losing in lots of name, always follow the same rule, if your name some element in your status like "statusTitle" the other element should be "statusDescription" but not "descriptionStatus"!

Comment: Thank you, those links were helpful but what about the names themselves? For example if i create a hello world project in eclipse it names the xml file like this: "activity_hello_world". Should all xml files start with activity? I understand that _ and small letters are used because xml doesent support capital letters.
Then again all class was named HelloWorldActivity - should all classes end with Activity?